# Automated method of setting ideal sizes and positions of symbols or logos of various proportions, when put together (ignoring any text)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, illustrator-scripting

I always spend too much time trying to scale symbols or logos that are supposed to look harmoniously next to each other, like below:

[image]

These seem to be acceptable to me, but I wonder if there is any formula or recipe that can be used to make a row of random proportions symbols look good and save time? I guess spacing also can be optimised, like in case of fonts. It probably depends on shapes of symbols, not only on their outer boundaries, but maybe there is some not too complicated solution?

It would be ideal to have a script that does it.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [DA01](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/306/da01) and [Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3270/scott) for suggesting a similar question ([What methods can I use to create balance and consistency between a group of differing logos?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50928/what-methods-can-i-use-to-create-balance-and-consistency-between-a-group-of-diff)), there are some great answers there. However they stress on importance of making the text look of similar size. At the moment I usually deal with symbols that rarely have text in it, so it is more a matter of balancing the geometry. **Ideally I'm interested in solution that could be scriptable, semi-automatic or fully-automatic**.

Comment: Hi ellockie, I see a very slight difference between this and the linked duplicate question, but my answer to this would essentially be the same as my answer to the marked duplicate. Just disregard the font size, balance your tallest and widest symbols to be roughly equal in size/"page presence", and then scale the other symbols to fit those boundaries. Defining consistent white space is the most important factor you have influence over when facing this task. Beyond that, there's no hard and fast formula for a group of varying images.

Comment: @Dom Thank you for the feedback. Yesterday and today I've been developing a method that is half-automatic (could be almost fully-automatic) and pretty effective. I'm happy tho share it together with a script that I'm going to write. I can modify the question title and content to stres the automation of that process, which is actually the most important to me, as (as I mentined in the first sentence) I spend too much time on "eyeballing".

Comment: there's a script to make a "contact sheet" here, it makes a grid of all symbols on the artboard, sized equally. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/837709

Comment: @CarlosCanto The thing is that making them equal doesn't make them look good next to each other.

Comment: @ellockie Agree scripts can only do so much, if you could explain the logic in "balancing the geometry" then a script may have a better chance of replicating it.

Comment: @CarlosCanto I mean making the symbols / logos sizes (ideally positions) look harmonious when placed in a row, without considering the size of the text if there is any. So none of them stands out in terms of size or position. All size transformations would keep the element's proportions. I'm currently working on such method, not 100% automatic (although but it could be), and I'll share it when it's ready. It's about automation of the process, so it would be good if I could publish it here...